# `sudo pecl install couchbase` gives an error of `ERROR: failed to mkdir /usr/local/Cellar/php/7.3.8/pecl/20180731`

Tags: php, macos, couchbase, lumen, pecl

I am setting up couchbase but when I try to install the Couchbase PHP extension by running the command `sudo pecl install couchbase` it fails with an error of `ERROR: failed to mkdir /usr/local/Cellar/php/7.3.8/pecl/20180731`

Comment: Is /usr/local/Cellar/php/7.3.8/pecl a symlink? If so, try remove symlink and run `sudo pecl install couchbase` : https://javorszky.co.uk/2018/05/03/getting-xdebug-working-on-php-7-2-and-homebrew/

Comment: Hi @CodeChef, thanks for checking out StackOverflow! I'm a little confused about the tags. You've tagged iOS, PHP, and Couchbase. Are you working on an iOS app? Then you probably need the couchbase-lite tag. Are you working on a PHP app? Then you probably don't want the iOS tag (I could be wrong, maybe there's a PHP framework for iOS. But nothing in this question seems iOS specific, or lumen specific for that matter)

Comment: @MatthewGroves thank you for showing me that mistake, I had to put macOS instead of iOS, I meant to say that I'm working with a MacBook. Let me change that.

Comment: You may want to file a bug report instead. Even though your question deals with some programming error, you don't ask a programming question. If you want to turn it into a programming question, you'd first have to extract a [mcve] from it. BTW, as a new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by uninstalling my HomeBrew-installed PHP-7.3 using `brew uninstall php@7.3` and then reinstalled it with `brew install php@7.3`.
After that, the command `sudo pecl install couchbase` was no longer bringing the error as before. Thank you @AndreaManzi, I got this idea from the link you provided in your comment on this question.